# Jsp form data not getting reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, forms

When we are trying to reset the form data in jsp the following code is executing, the data is getting reset but again the data is appearing back from somewhere  **$('input[type="text"]').val('');**

Comment: from somewhere?Please post your code in the question

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" name="${names}${i}" style="padding:0px;background-color:AliceBlue;text-align: center;text-transform:uppercase;" value="${data[i-1]}">

Comment: this is the code used to generate the input field

Comment: Its a good practice to to be clear in the question.Please find the instructions to use StackOverflow.

Comment: How & when are you calling `$('input[type="text"]').val('')`?

Comment: @Manish Sharma  need your over all code to analyze this situation. From this data we can not predict from where it is coming

Answer (score 1):

A reset in form of `$('input[type="text"]').val('')` resets the value in the browser only. But the value attribut of the input field is `value="${data[i-1]}"`. This means, the next update to this input field (page reload or ajax call with update) will set the value of this input field back to the value of data[i-1];